# How to convert a hex binary string to Uint8Array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this string of bytes represented in hex:

```
const s = "\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\x8bV23J15O4\xb14\xb1H61417KKLL\xb50L5U\x8a\x05\x00\xf6\xaa\x8e.\x1c\x00\x00\x00"
```

I would like to convert it to Uint8Array in order to further manipulate it.

How can it be done?

**Update:**

The binary string is coming from python backend. In python I can create this representation correctly:

```
encoded = base64.b64encode(b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\x8bV23J15O4\xb14\xb1H61417KKLL\xb50L5U\x8a\x05\x00\xf6\xaa\x8e.\x1c\x00\x00\x00')
```

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen i updated the question about where this string is coming from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since JavaScript strings support `\x` escapes, this should work to convert a Python byte string to a `Uint8Array` :

```js
const s = "\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\x8bV23J15O4\xb14\xb1H61417KKLL\xb50L5U\x8a\x05\x00\xf6\xaa\x8e.\x1c\x00\x00\x00";

const array = Uint8Array.from([...s].map(v => v.charCodeAt(0)));

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Node.js, one uses [`Buffer.from`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#static-method-bufferfromarray) to convert a (base64-encoded) string into a `Buffer`.

If the original argument is a base64 encoded string, as in Python:

```js
const buffer = Buffer.from(encodedString, 'base64');
```

It if's a UTF-8 encoded string:

```js
const buffer = Buffer.from(encodedString);
```

`Buffer`s are instances of `Uint8Array`, so they can be used wherever a `Uint8Array` is expected. Quoting from the docs:

> The `Buffer` class is a subclass of JavaScript's `Uint8Array` class and extends it with methods that cover additional use cases. Node.js APIs accept plain `Uint8Array`s wherever `Buffer`s are supported as well.

Comment: Where is the `base64` coming from?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I think it's this line in the question: `encoded = base64.b64encode...`. [edit]: maybe I was misreading the question, I've updated my answer to clarify things.

Answer (score -1):

```js
const s = "\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\x8bV23J15O4\xb14\xb1H61417KKLL\xb50L5U\x8a\x05\x00\xf6\xaa\x8e.\x1c\x00\x00\x00"

//btoa(base64) - transforms base64 to ascii
let str = btoa(s)

let encoder = new TextEncoder()

let typedarr = encoder.encode(str) //encode() returns Uint8Array

console.log(typedarr)
```

Comment: I would expect a 48-byte string to convert to a 48-element array, and null bytes (`\x00`) to have a value of `0` in that array. Yet, your array has 63 elements and null bytes get the value `65`.